# laravel 5.1 Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\Authcontroller@postLogin); not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working in Laravel 5.1, the login used to work fine but I changed the default Users Table to admin_users and problem started. The 
`Route::post('auth/login','Auth\Authcontroller@getLogin');` 
works fine but When I try to login, it redirects to the same page.
Below is the part of Routes.php page. I want the login to lead to index page from DashboardController.

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.', 
'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('index');
});
```

What do you think is the problem? Can anyone suggest or help?

Comment: check logs inside storage/logs

Comment: change model name for user from `config/auth.php`

Comment: @GaneshGhalame config/auth.php has already been updated

Comment: set error_reporting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display also try `dd('here') `and check your method is getting called

Comment: also run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` model declare the custom table like so:

```
public $table = "admin_users";
```

And in your config folder, open `auth.php` and make sure under `providers > users` the driver is `eloquent` and the correct model path that corresponds to your `User` model is specified.

Comment: Everything is fine there. User model has the statement `protected $table = "admin_users";` The auth.php file is also fine.